# Java debugger can't call some default method implementations

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, interface, java-8, default-method

I'm coding in IntelliJ IDEA. When debugging my application, I can't use some default method implementations in *Watches*.

Here is a condensed example:

```
public class Friendship {
    interface Friend {
        default void sayHiTo(Friend friend) {
            System.out.println("Hi, " + friend.hashCode());
        }

        default int amountOfHands() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public static class BasicFriend implements Friend {

        int numberOfFaces() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Put a breakpoint here");
    }
}
```

In `main()` method I put a breakpoint and set up three watches:

```
// Default interface method with dependency
new BasicFriend().sayHiTo(new BasicFriend())

// Default interface method without dependency
new BasicFriend().amountOfHands()

// Class method
new BasicFriend().numberOfFaces()
```

The first watch throws `NoSuchMethodException` complaining that method `Friendship$BasicFriend.sayHiTo()` doesn't exist.

The second watch runs successfully, but strangely it reports a boxed object
`{java.lang.Integer@537} "2"` instead of just a primitive `2`.

The third watch reports a primitive 1, just as expected.

Why is the first watch not working? Is this a bug? Is this actually IDE related? Is it because of some conceptual flaw of default methods? Should it be working as I want it to in the first place? Is the strange result of the second watch somehow related to the issue in the first watch?

Comment: After rereading your question, I get the same except for your first watch. In your first watch I get `java.lang.ClassCastException : com.sun.tools.jdi.InterfaceTypeImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.jdi.ClassTypeImpl`. I'm guessing this is just an IntelliJ compiler bug. I am using IntelliJ 14.1.2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to JDK 8u40, default and static interface methods were not supported by JDI (Java Debugger Interface), JDWP (Java Debugger Wire Protocol) and JDB (the standard Java debugger).  This is [bug JDK-8042123](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8042123), which is recorded as fixed in 8u40 and a corresponding blurb appears in the [8u40 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u40-relnotes-2389089.html).

Update to 8u40 or later to fix this issue, at least on the JDK side.

From the bug description, it looks like debugger-side changes are also required, to avoid casting com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType objects to com.sun.jdi.ClassType, but instead call InterfaceType.invokeMethod() directly.

In the specific case of IntelliJ, [Suseika confirmed in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036474/java-debugger-cant-call-some-default-method-implementations/30038411?noredirect=1#comment48197080_30038411) that 14.1.2 has mostly fixed the issue (except the unexpected boxing), though [Mike Kobit still experiences this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036474/java-debugger-cant-call-some-default-method-implementations/30038411?noredirect=1#comment48190156_30036474) on that version with a ClassCastException suggestive of the incorrect cast above.

Comment: I had Java 8u45 installed, but still got the NoSuchMethodException. However, updating IntelliJ IDEA from 14.0.3 to 14.1.2 did the trick — now default methods in the debugger work almost properly (the second one still returns boxed object, but that's for another question).

Comment: @Suseika Thanks for the information (edited into the answer).  That seems to confirm that debugger-side changes are required.

Comment: About boxing. I filed a bug report on that, you can find it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139945