# Missing invokeMethod in com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType

Tags: java, java-8

In Oracle Javadocs for Java 8 it is specified that [InterfaceType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/InterfaceType.html) has a method named `invokeMethod`.

However when I check on my system I don't see any such method in the Interface:

```
kshitiz:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/lib$ javap -classpath tools.jar com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType
Compiled from "InterfaceType.java"
public interface com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType extends com.sun.jdi.ReferenceType {
  public abstract java.util.List<com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType> superinterfaces();
  public abstract java.util.List<com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType> subinterfaces();
  public abstract java.util.List<com.sun.jdi.ClassType> implementors();
}
```

Java version check:

```
kshitiz:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/lib$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Output of `java -version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing different versions it seems that Oracle has added the method in minor update `u40`. Versions below that don't have this method.

On JDK `1.8.0_40`:

```
Compiled from "InterfaceType.java"
public interface com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType extends com.sun.jdi.ReferenceType {
  public abstract java.util.List<com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType> superinterfaces();
  public abstract java.util.List<com.sun.jdi.InterfaceType> subinterfaces();
  public abstract java.util.List<com.sun.jdi.ClassType> implementors();
  public com.sun.jdi.Value invokeMethod(com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference, com.sun.jdi.Method, java.util.List<? extends com.sun.jdi.Value>, int) throws com.sun.jdi.InvalidTypeException, com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException, com.sun.jdi.IncompatibleThreadStateException, com.sun.jdi.InvocationException;
}
```

I was surprised by this since such structural changes are supposed to happen only between major versions not between minor revisions. However `com.sun` packages are considered private Oracle API and [subject to change anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1834826/1345655).

Comment: I've got 1.8.0_45 and can see the method.

Comment: @Kshitiz `com.sun` packages are allowed to change at any time; they're treated as private implementation details

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do I have any references for that? I'm skeptical because there are plenty of third party debugging tools that rely on these packages.

Comment: @KshitizSharma, just because people use something doesn't magically extend official API stability guarantees to those parts too. In fact, I did have observed debugging tools break on between java updates.

Comment: @KshitizSharma See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes

Comment: I concede. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: don’t mix up `sun.*` packages with `com.sun.*` packages. The latter contain some vendor specific APIs which are, well, just vendor specific, but not private. One example is the API discussed here, as the link in the question already shows, it’s a *documented* API.

Comment: @Kshitiz Sharma: it’s a `default` method which has been added, so it’s unlikely to break anything, but its absence in Java 8 has been considered a bug that must be fixed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/30038411/2711488